# How to prevent table cell borders from "bleeding" into each other

Tags: html, css, html-table

```css
html {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
td {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
th:first-child, td:first-child {
  border-left-style: none;
}
th:last-child, td:last-child {
  border-right-style: none;
}
th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
}
th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
}
tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom-style: none;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
}
tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      ::selection {
        background-color: #0dd; color: #099;
      }
      table, th, td {
        padding: 1rem;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #eee;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      table {
        margin-top: 1rem;
        border-style: none;
      }
      th {
        border-top-style: none;
        border-color: #111;
        background-color: #222;
        color: #fff;
        border-bottom-color: #fff;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr> <th>One</th><th>Two</th><th>Three</th> </tr>
      <tr> <td>four</td> <td>five</td><td>six</td> </tr> 
      <tr> <td>seven</td> <td>eight</td><td>nine</td> </tr>  
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

The vertical table borders in the `<th>` elements are extending down into the horizontal top border on the `<td>` elements below. How do we prevent this and have the borders look normal without "bleeding" into each other?

I've stripped this down to a very simple example with simple code as to isolate the problem. I'm still not finding a solution.

**Edit**: This is only seeming to appear in Chrome currently. Not sure if this is a known bug with a quick hack/fix. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like this issue is related to the browser. I ran your code on Firefox I did not see any issue. any issue. On chrome I was able to see the bleeding issue

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti It's such a weird glitch. I wonder if anyone's run into this before and has any quick and dirty chrome hacks for a fix?

Comment: Not sure though, I have bookmarked and upvoted your question in the hopes someone will address it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Simple rather then using white `bottom border` use black see below

```css
html {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
td {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
th:first-child, td:first-child {
  border-left-style: none;
}
th:last-child, td:last-child {
  border-right-style: none;
}
th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
}
th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
}
tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom-style: none;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
}
tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      ::selection {
        background-color: #0dd; color: #099;
      }
      table, th, td {
        padding: 1rem;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #eee;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      table {
        margin-top: 1rem;
        border-style: none;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      th {
      border-top-style: none;
      border-color: #111;
      background-color: #222;
      color: #fff;
      border-bottom-color: #222;
      position: relative;
  }
  th::before {
      content: '';
      height: 2px;
width: 105%;/*its not proper solution but a hack*/
position: absolute;
bottom: -3px;
left:0;
right:0;
background: red;
  }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr> <th>One</th><th>Two</th><th>Three</th> </tr>
      <tr> <td>four</td> <td>five</td> <td>six</td> </tr> 
      <tr> <td>seven</td> <td>eight</td> <td>nine</td> </tr>  
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** for border between `table header` and `table body` please edit `th::before`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this case however i want a small spacer/border between the table head elements and table cell elements. So I cannot make the table head elements have a black bottom border as shown here. **Setting them white in my code was deliberate.**

Comment: @devsandbox i didnt get your point! you need border/separator of different color between `table` `head` and `body` right?

Comment: Yes. I prefer the 1px small gap between the `<th>` and the `<td>`s. Its' small I know however that is what led me to this problem in the first place. that 1px wide gap between top and lower cells.

Comment: Thx. i'll upvote you while i play around with this code. I'm not sure this is the most sustainable answer but its helpful nonetheless.

Comment: Sure i m also brainstorming for the best approach will share with you if i get one :)

Comment: @devsandbox There is one more approach to achieve this by using two `tables` and giving first table `border-bottom`.

Comment: The best solution I found was to change the bottom border color of `thead` to match it's background color with slightly extra thickness. Then to add a space between the table head and table cells I used CSS transforms to translate the whole table head up a little vertically.

Comment: Yes, a little but complicated one but still a better approach :) Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

```css
html {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
td {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
th:first-child, td:first-child {
  border-left-style: none;
}
th:last-child, td:last-child {
  border-right-style: none;
}
th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
}
th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
}
tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom-style: none;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
}
tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      ::selection {
        background-color: #0dd; color: #099;
      }
      table, th, td {
        padding: 1rem;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #eee;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      table {
        margin-top: 1rem;
        border-style: none;
      }
      th {
        border-top-style: none;
        border-color: #111;
        background-color: #222;
        color: #fff;
        border-bottom-color: #fff;
        border-bottom: double;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr> <th>One</th><th>Two</th><th>Three</th> </tr>
      <tr> <td>four</td> <td>five</td> <td>six</td> </tr> 
      <tr> <td>seven</td> <td>eight</td> <td>nine</td> </tr>  
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```